How to use the .onDelete modifier on a filtered list
I created a small SwiftData project, hosting a list with an .onDelete modifier.
In order to filter the list I extracted the list into a separate ListView and set the filter using the init method.
But I found no way to use the .onDelete modifier from inside the ListView.
I guess the modelContext from the ContentView is missing in the ListView, but I wasn’t able to make it available.
The sample data contains user12, user13, user22.
ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment (\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @State private var filteringList = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ListView(filterByUserName: filteringList ? "1" : "user")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("Filter list") {
                    filteringList.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ListView
struct ListView: View {
    
    @Query var users: [UserModel]
    
    init(filterByUserName: String) {
        _users = Query(filter: #Predicate<UserModel> { user in user.name.contains(filterByUserName)},
                       sort: \UserModel.name)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(users) { user in
                Text(user.name)
            }

//How can I use .onDelete in ListView?
//            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
//                deleteUser(at: indexSet)
//            })
        }
    }
}


Why not use @Environment (\.modelContext) in the ListView as well?

given you add @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext,
you could try something like this:
.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in  for index in indexSet {      modelContext.delete(users[index])  } })

Thanks. Adding @Environment in ListView did the trick.
